# Any tip to to make this jQuery popup script responsive in order to view on mobile devicess

Tags: responsive, popupwindow

```
<!-- POP UP Start --><!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#overlay').fadeIn(500,function(){
            $('#popup').show();
         });

         $(".close").on('click', function() {
            $('#popup').hide();
            $('#overlay').fadeOut(500);
         });
      });
   </script>
<div id="overlay" style ="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; opacity: 0.6; filter: alpha(opacity=60); z-index: 5; display: none"></div>
<div id="popup" style="position:fixed; display:hidden; top:150px; left:50%; width:500px; height:auto; margin-left:-250px; background-color:#FFFFFF; z-index:6; padding:20px; border:solid 5px #2A1D9E; border-radius:5px;">
<a href="URL TO YOUR SITE" class="close" style="display: block; float:right; position:relative; top:-15px; right: -15px; height: 20px; color:#FFFFFF;">X</a>
<p style=color:#FFFFFF;">
</p>
<p style="margin:0; padding:5px; text-align:justify;">
<a href=https://www.google.com><img class="aligncenter wp-image-21 size-full" src=imageurl.png alt="ALT TEXT" width="500" height="300" /></a>
</p>
<a href=https://www.google.com style="margin:0; padding:5px; text-align:right; float:right; color:#333333;">CALL TO ACTION TEXT CLICK HERE</a>
</div>
<!-- POP UP End -->
```

Appreciate your support to make this code responsive, so that popup can be views on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way is to write a `media-query` and reduce the width of the `#popup` for a smaller screen.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #popup{
    width: 300px !important;
  }
}
```

If you have control over the html elements, please avoid writing inline styles and set the width in percentage values so that you need not write media-queries.

Also, just FYI, if you don't need to support old browsers, you could use `transform:translateX(-50%);` to keep the `#popup` horizontally center aligned instead of using negative margins.

Hope this helps. Let me know.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your input, my apology for noob question, where exactly should I insert media query? and transform:translate as well, thanks for your patience..

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, you need to avoid writing inline styles and write it in a different css file altogether. You can find the references in w3schools website.